# hamster time tracker in kubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, hamster

I'm trying to install the hamster time tracker in Kubuntu 20.04, but it seems quite difficult. Has anyone got it working?

hamster itself is not present in the official repos, but I installed hamster-snap from [here](https://snapcraft.io/install/hamster-snap/kde-neon). That works, but I'd also like to have a way to put it in the KDE system tray.

Earlier (in Kubuntu 16.04) that was possible with [hamster-tray](https://www.janhouse.lv/blog/linux/hamster-time-tracker-in-system-tray/) but that seems to be defunct now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible by following two steps below.

Get `hamster-time-tracker` package from [*groovy*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/hamster-time-tracker):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hamster-time-tracker/hamster-time-tracker_3.0.2-3_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./hamster-time-tracker_3.0.2-3_all.deb
```

Clone Hamster `unity-indicator` [repository](https://github.com/projecthamster/unity-indicator) and install the indicator to the system:

```
sudo apt-get install git python-is-python3 gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 python3-gi-cairo
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/projecthamster/unity-indicator.git

cd unity-indicator
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
sudo cp data/hamster-indicator.gschema.xml /usr/local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/local/share/glib-2.0/schemas
sudo cp hamster-indicator /usr/local/bin/hamster-indicator

mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications
cp data/hamster-indicator.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
sed -i "s|Icon=hamster-time-tracker|Icon=hamster-indicator-active|" ~/.local/share/applications/hamster-indicator.desktop
sed -i "s|Exec=/usr/bin/hamster-indicator|Exec=/usr/local/bin/hamster-indicator|" ~/.local/share/applications/hamster-indicator.desktop

mkdir -p ~/.local/share/pixmaps
cp data/icons/hicolor/24x24/* ~/.local/share/pixmaps/
cp data/icons/hicolor/scalable/* ~/.local/share/pixmaps/
```

and enjoy:

> [image: Hamster with Indicator on Kubuntu 20.04 LTS]

Also it is possible to make it working on MATE with commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads/unity-indicator
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/24/
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/24/
cp /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/index.theme ~/.local/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark
cp /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/index.theme ~/.local/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light
cp data/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/24x24/* ~/.local/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/24/
cp data/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/24x24/* ~/.local/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/24/
gtk-update-icon-cache ~/.local/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark
gtk-update-icon-cache ~/.local/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light
```

to get the following:

> [image: Hamster with Indicator on Ubuntu MATE 20.04]

Comment: This was working for some time, but since recently I get the an error `NotImplementedError: received <class 'datetime.timedelta'>` when running `hamster-indicator`. Do you know why? (Or is that perhaps better to ask on github.)

Comment: You have to check changes in your python configuration, I think. Hamster uses python3, not python2.

Comment: I had the same strange issue `NotImplementedError: received <class 'datetime.timedelta'>`. To fix the problem I added these 2 lines to file `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/hamster/lib/stuff.py` after line 162:
```
    elif hasattr(duration, 'total_seconds'):
        return duration.total_seconds() / 60
```