# Hamster time tracker won't launch in 18.04

Tags: hamster

I upgraded from 16.04 a while ago and got hamster time tracker to work with 18.04, but today after reboot the app is not launching any more. I click the launcher and nothing happens. How can I debug this? I recall there is a terminal command to start it, but cannot find it any more.

I'm pretty sure it is not this, but tried and got a syntax error

```
$ hamster-time-tracker
  File "/usr/bin/hamster-time-tracker", line 89
    except dbus.DBusException, e:
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Looks rather like an error due to running a Python 2 program with a Python 3 interpreter. You might want to try installing a newer version of Hamster, since it migrated to Python 3 [a while ago](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster/releases/tag/v2.1.1). Otherwise, try installing Python 2 (`sudo apt-get install python2.7`) and running it with that (`python2.7 /usr/bin/hamster-time-tracker`).

Comment: Looks like I was actually using the old hamster-applet, the UI in those newer apps is completely different, and to be honest, worse. The old applet UI was perfect, simple and extremely efficient. Unfortunately I removed the old hamster from my machine in hopes of getting the new one working. Now looking for how to install the old back.

Comment: You can try to adapt the solution for 20.04 - see [hamster time tracker in kubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298849/hamster-time-tracker-in-kubuntu-20-04) .

Comment: @N0rbert That seems to be installing the version 3.0.2, which is the newest at the time. I have it now installed from sources. It's just awful. Trying to log a time for yesterday is so painful, the time and date selectors are bugging all the time. The only way I can log time with it is by using the cmdline "2021-04-19 11:00 - 13:00 CompanyA". I suppose I need to learn to live with it.

Comment: If you really want an old version back, you could download [an older release from the project's GitHub](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster/releases) and install it from source. (It's Python, so I'm guessing it won't be that tricky…) Then you'd just have to make sure it runs with `python2.7`.